# What's the simplest way to format a .NET DateTime according to YYYYMMDD or the like?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatting

I have a DateTime class and wish to display it according to some format... in this case, I specifically want to format it as YYYYMMDD format.

What's the best C#/.NET API function for doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always use this site to get any dates formats etc.
http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 6):

ToString(format)? i.e.

```
string s = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

(note the case)

Answer (score 2):

```
myDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Here you can find a comprehesive list of DateTime patterns and pattern characters: 
[DateTime.ToString() Patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.ToString(<format string>)
```

Look at the docs for the format string details.