# Convert DateTime to string with format YYYYMMDD

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, datetime, formatting

I have birth dates stored as datetime in SQL Server 2008 like so:

```
2010-04-25 00:00:00.000
```

What is the best way, using C#, to convert and format this into a string with a `YYYYMMDD` format?

In the end, all I need is a string like:

```
20100425
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to format a .NET DateTime according to YYYYMMDD or the like?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406487/whats-the-simplest-way-to-format-a-net-datetime-according-to-yyyymmdd-or-the-li)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Should be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get that value into a DateTime object and then you can use it's ToString() function like so:

```
.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to get the data out of the database as a DateTime (.NET) object? If so, you can use the DateTime's  instancename.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

If you haven't gotten to that stage yet, there's quite a few different ways to get the data out. It's a whole Google search in itself...

Answer (score 1):

You just format the date using a custom format string:

```
string formatted = theDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Note that the date doens't have a format at all when it's stored as a datetime in the database. It's just a point in time, it doesn't have a specific text representation until it's specifically created from the date.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .ToString() method on the date time object, and pass in the format you want.