# How to convert DateTime to/from specific string format (both ways, e.g. given Format is "yyyyMMdd")?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I am having a problem converting a datetime which is in string format but I am not able to convert it using `"yyyyMMdd"` format.

My code is:

```
string tpoc = refSubClaim.BenefitsFolder.BenefitFolderIdNumber.ToString();
string[] tpocinfo = Regex.Split(tpoc,";");

for (int i = 0; i < tpocinfo.Length; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            string[] tpoc2 = Regex.Split(tpocinfo[0], ",");
            claimantAuxillaryRecord.TPOCDate2 = tpoc2[0].ToString();
            claimantAuxillaryRecord.TPOCAmount2 = Convert.ToDecimal(tpoc2[1]);
            claimantAuxillaryRecord.FundingDelayedBeyondTPOCStartDate2 = tpoc2[2].ToString();
        }
        break;
```

Comment: What format is the datetime string in right now?

Comment: And what's the relevance of your code snippet to the question?

Comment: I'm a little unclear; are you working with a string representation of a date, or a DateTime object? Assuming it's a DateTime object you can just call `obj.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`;

Comment: Actually TPOCDate2 is already a variable and i just want to convert the elemnts in tpoc2[0] to be in the yyyyMMdd format.
Hope this answers your question

Comment: Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to format a .NET DateTime according to YYYYMMDD or the like?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406487/whats-the-simplest-way-to-format-a-net-datetime-according-to-yyyymmdd-or-the-l)

Comment: try this Convert.ToDateTime(tpoc2[0]).ToString("yyyyMMdd");

Answer (score 242, accepted):

if you have a date in a string with the format "ddMMyyyy" and want to convert it to "yyyyMMdd" you could do like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddMMyyyy", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: Got stuck with your code, this one worked well DateTime.TryParse(stringValue, out outputInDateTime);

Answer (score 67):

### Parsing DateTime:

To parse a DateTime, use one of the following methods:

- [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx)
- [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

Alternatively, you may use [try-parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009.aspx) pattern:

- [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.TryParse.aspx)
- [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.TryParseExact.aspx)

Read more about [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

### Converting DateTime to a string:

To return a DateTime as a string in "yyyyMMdd" format, you may use [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx) method.

- Code snippet example: `string date = DateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd");`
- Note upper-cased **M**'s refer to months and lower-cased **m**'s to minutes.

### Your case:

In your case, assuming you don't want to handle scenario when date is different format or misssing, it would be most convenient to use `ParseExact`:

```
string dateToParse = "20170506";
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToParse, 
                                          "yyyyMMdd",
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This is an old topic, but for those searching, the link above, "culture-specific format" is now a dead link. Here is one that is current and informative [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 42):

You can convert your string to a `DateTime` value like this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(something);
```

You can convert a `DateTime` value to a formatted string like this:

```
date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 11):

String to yyyy-MM-dd date format:
Example:

```
TxtCalStDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(objItem["StartDate"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to have **DATE** as string with **TIME** as well. We can do like this:

```
    //Date and Time is taking as current system Date-Time    
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
```

Comment: minutes shoulde be small "m" !? "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"

Answer (score 6):

Use  `DateTime.TryParseExact()` if you want to match against a specific date format

```
   string format = "yyyyMMdd"; 
    DateTime dateTime;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                             DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `DateTime.TryParse()` instead of `DateTime.Parse()`.
With `TryParse()` you have a return value if it was successful and with `Parse()` you have to handle an exception

Answer (score 5):

Simply just do in this way.

```
string yourFormat = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

It's the Simple way to convert to format

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 3):

> no its a string with yyyy/mm/dd and i need it in yyyyMMdd format

If you only need to remove the slashes from a string don't you just replace them?

Example:

```
myDateString = "2013/03/28";
myDateString = myDateString.Replace("/", "");
```

myDateString should now be "20130328".

Less of an overkill :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the property names it looks like you are trying to convert a string to a date by assignment:

```
claimantAuxillaryRecord.TPOCDate2 = tpoc2[0].ToString();
```

It is probably due to the current UI culture and therefore it cannot interpret the date string correctly when assigned.

Comment: no its a string with yyyy/mm/dd and i need it in yyyyMMdd format

Comment: and while doing 
claimantAuxillaryRecord.TPOCDate2 = tpoc2[0].ToString("yyyyMMdd");
it gives some build errors.
The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguements

Comment: @Matt - really? You edited a 4+ year response that wasn't even marked as the answer to add a tab? That's a serious bad case of OCD you've got there.

Answer (score 2):

From C# 6:

```
var dateTimeUtcAsString = $"{DateTime.UtcNow:o}";
```

The result will be: "2019-01-15T11:46:33.2752667Z"

Answer (score 0):

A more simple way I came across while searching for this answer as well;

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: How about I have a value for `DateTime`? Like  `DateTime newDate = DateTime.Parse(Session["date"].ToString());`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these codes

```
claimantAuxillaryRecord.TPOCDate2  = Convert.ToDateTime(tpoc2[0]).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Or

```
claimantAuxillaryRecord.TPOCDate2 = Convert.ToDateTime(tpoc2[0]).ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: For the love of god (our lord savior Harambe), never use Convert.ToDateTime... This thing is so slow (~100ms)! Just use ParseExact or TryParse - waaaaay faster!!!