# get todays date in Web Service application

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created a web service to send emails with attachments.  The attachment location is passed via a string called "StrAttachment".  I can pass the actual location of the folder, but this service will run everytime a sale is made to email documents to a client.  The location of the folder will always be "C:", but a new folder will be created everyday named by the date, for eg : 20121018.  So I need to pass that name to the StrAttachment parameter, so my web service knows which folder to look in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well you have got `DateTime.Today` ! !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your parameter using DateTime.ToString() and specifying the format:

```
string StrAttachment = "C:\\" + //your drive letter
                       DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") +  //your current date
                       "yourFoldername"; //other name in the folder (if any)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

It should be something like DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

Answer (score 0):

You can get current date with `DateTime.Today`. You can use it to extract the formatted current data as

```
folderName = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

There is a quite similar question (well, it doesn't involve the folder part)
[Convert DateTime to string format("yyyyMMdd")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477735/convert-datetime-to-string-formatyyyymmdd)