# String is not valid Datetime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I am writing this code the text Change event but it is showing the error that is string is not valid.

```
 DateTime ts=Convert.ToDateTime(Joiningdate.Text);
   DateTime dt1=ts.AddMonths(6);
    txtcd.Text = dt1.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTime format does not match the format you need to convert string to DateTime object. You can use [**DateTime.ParseExact()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) to give you format you date you have.

Assuming you have format dd/MM/YY for the textbox

```
DateTime ts= DateTime.ParseExact(Joiningdate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt1=ts.AddMonths(6);
txtcd.Text = dt1.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the format of `Joiningdate.Text`
You will have to tell that in what format your date time is.

If your date time is in format use

```
DateTime ts= DateTime.ParseExact(Joiningdate.Text, "ddMMyyyy", 
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt1=ts.AddMonths(6);
```

nd then you can convert back to any format you want

```
ts.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

You can go through this link

[Convert DateTime to string format("yyyyMMdd")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477735/convert-datetime-to-string-formatyyyymmdd)