# ASP.NET Razor C# to TypeScript/JavaScript equivalent for SqlDateTime

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, typescript

I'm working on converting an older `.cshtml` view file into pure `HTML` + `TypeScript` using `Angular1`. In this instance `Angular` really hasn't much to do with the issue as much as finding the equivalent functionality in `TypeScript` (or `JavaScript`) from some `C#` code within a `Razor` view.

The old code was the following:

`ng-init="
vm.defaultStartDate='@SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value'; vm.defaultEndDate='@SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value'"`

In the updated code, these values will not be set in the view; there's no reason for that. The `Angular` controller logic written in `TypeScript` can initialize these values and use them when required. The problem is, I'm trying to figure out the equivelent code in `TypeScript/JavaScript` and I can't seem to come up with the correct implementation.

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), `@SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value` will equate to the following:

> The minimum valid date for a SqlDateTime structure is January 1, 1753

And from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) for `@SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value`:

> The maximum valid date for a SqlDateTime structure is December 31, 9999.

I've tried the following, but when executed I'm getting an issue on the server that the dates are not defined properly. When I debug in `TypeScript` they don't match the original versions either.

```
this.defaultStartDate = String(new Date('1/1/1753'));
this.defaultEndDate = String(new Date('12/31/9999'));
```

Certainly there is a better way I can initialize those dates and I'm sure I'm missing something trivial. What's the best way to set those dates using `TypeScript/JavaScript` to be essentially the bookend start/end default dates that the old `C#` code was doing?

Answer (score 0):

Either convert you date to yyyy-mm-dd or client varient. You can refer to following link for the same.

[Convert DateTime to string format("yyyyMMdd")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477735/convert-datetime-to-string-formatyyyymmdd)