# Convert a formmated string (dd/mm/yy) to and ISO datetime

Tags: c#, date-format

I have a `string` variable named `ProjectDateSigned` which have this format `13/10/2019 23:00:00`, and I need to convert it to *ISO standard* as follow `2019-10-13T23:00:00Z`, so how I can do so? i am following the UK time local.

```
DateTime ISOdatetimeCustom = i["ProjectDateSinged"];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format

Comment: If the code above actually works your value is already a `DateTime`, and you're just seeing the format the debugger is using for displaying the value. In that case you want the opposite, i.e. [`DateTime` to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3477735/4137916)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParseExact` to `DateTime` and then format `ToString` back:

```
string source = "13/10/2019 23:00:00";

string result = DateTime
  .ParseExact(source, "d'/'M'/'yyyy' 'H':'m':'s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  .ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");
```

If you already have a `DateTime` (i.e. if `i["ProjectDateSinged"]` returns `DateTime`), just format it:

```
 string result = i["ProjectDateSinged"].ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
string myDate = "13/10/2019 23:00:00";

if (DateTime.TryParse(myDate, out var convertedDate))
{
     string output = convertedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
}
```

Comment: And just hope that it works out in locales that use MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: The question states UK format is being followed....

Comment: True, but thought must always be given to future visitors to a question/simple robustitudes that can be applied to make the code more portable and less likely to develop bugs if one day they just happen to install the program in a different region

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do date/time conversions you can split and re-join the string:

```
var bits = i["ProjectDateSinged"].Split('/', ' ');
string newFormat = $"{bits[2]}-{bits[1]}-{bits[0]}T{bits[3]}Z";
```

Comment: And just hope that it works out in locales that use dd.MM.yyyy?