# Adjacent Datetime Format in .net

Tags: .net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the simplest way to format a .NET DateTime according to YYYYMMDD or the like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406487/whats-the-simplest-way-to-format-a-net-datetime-according-to-yyyymmdd-or-the-l)

Is there any adjacent datetime format in .net like 20121008 (as today's date) ?

Comment: ...and probably a million more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`custom DateTime format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
string formattedDate = today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```